# Fancybox not displayed

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I got the following code:

```
    Html.AddScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js");
    Html.AddCssFileParts("~/Content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css");


$().ready(function () {
alert('yo')
        $("#leistungsPopup").fancybox();
}

 <div style="display:none" id="leistungsPopup">
        <h1>YO feel the FLow!</h1>

    </div>
```

The Fancybox does not show up. The Fancybox-files are loaed (js and css) and the alert is shown. Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you checked console for errors?

Comment: None there. I can even step over the code without problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to show a div with display set to none.
Include a wrapper div with display set to none and remove it from the div you want to show.
Like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="leistungsPopup">
        <h1>YO feel the FLow!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="TriggerFancybox" href="#leistungsPopup" style="display: none;"></a>
```

Edit: apparantly a fancybox popup is triggered by a click. If you change your JavaScript code to the following, it should work, see this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDNrq/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TriggerFancybox").fancybox().trigger("click");
});
```

Edit 2: updated the answer to work with jQuery Fancybox 1.3.4. This means triggering a click on a hidden link in the document ready.

Comment: @ZiNNED - heads up: your jsfiddle is using fancybox v2.x and its html won't work with v1.3.4, which is actually the OP's issue. Try updating your jsfiddle to match with the proposed code as in your answer (which I think is the correct one by the way)

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the heads up. I've updated the answer to reflect changes needed to work with v.1.3.4.